# Проблема с переключением цвета логотипа в темный режим

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

У меня есть логотип черного цвета для моего портфолио, и я хотел бы переключить его на белый в темном режиме. https://www.paulinerouger.com/

Я пытался сделать:

- **Используя CSS переменные:**

```
<img class="nav_logo" src="assets/img/PR_logo.png" alt="original logo" />

body {
  --nav_logo: url(PR_logo.png) no-repeat;

}

body[data-theme="dark"] {
  --nav_logo: url(PR_logo_white.png) no-repeat;
}

.nav_logo {
    background: var(--nav_logo);
  }
```

- **Сделать с помощью SVG**

```
<img class="nav_logo" src="assets/img/PR_logo.svg" id="svg" alt="PR Logo">


.nav_logo {
    fill: currentColor;
}
```

К сожалению, ничего из вышеперечисленного не сработало.
Любое предложение решения задачи?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Switch Logo color in Dark Mode issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71013868/7394871) от участника  [@PaulineTW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16621883/paulinetw).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/71013868/7394871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться свойством [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content), которому можно задать значение с помощью css-переменных.

Например:

```js
document.getElementById('toggleButton').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (this.innerHTML === "Dark") {
    document.body.dataset.theme = "dark";
    this.innerHTML = "Light";
  } else {
    document.body.dataset.theme = "light";
    this.innerHTML = "Dark";
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  --nav_logo: url(https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/169/169367.png);
}

body[data-theme="dark"] {
  --nav_logo: url(https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/196/196685.png);
}

.nav_logo {
  content: var(--nav_logo);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="toggleButton">Dark</button>

  <img id="logo" class="nav_logo" alt="original logo" width="100" height="100" />
</body>
```

Comment: ♦ Спасибо за вариант ответа. Кстати разморозь пожалуйста [SVG чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы рассматриваете решение на основе JS, вы можете использовать подход, который я разработал ниже.
Щелчок по кнопке изменяет как атрибут `src` элемента `<img>`, так и стиль `background-color` элемента `<body>`.

```js
let button = document.getElementById('toggleButton');
let logo = document.getElementById('logo');

let darkImageURL = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuKoK.png";
let lightImageURL = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJSxu.png";

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if(this.innerHTML === "Dark") {
    document.body.style.background = "black";
    this.innerHTML = "Light";
    logo.src = darkImageURL;
  }
  else {
    document.body.style.background = "white";
    this.innerHTML = "Dark";
    logo.src = lightImageURL;
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="toggleButton">Dark</button>

  <img id="logo" class="nav_logo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJSxu.png" alt="original logo" width="100" height="100"/>
</body>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71014124/7394871) от участника  [@Sercan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15032688/sercan).</sub>

Comment: привет когда в первый раз нажимаешь на кнопку dark фон меняется сразу а картинка нет

Comment: @Leks это происходит из-за размера картинок, пока они подгрузятся Сейчас попробую уменьшить их размер