# Смена иконки, смена темы(окраски страницы) по нажатию

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

У меня 2 вопроса:

1. как при нажатии на черный полумесяц вся страница была черной, а не только блок где я его вставил, потому что когда вставляю это туда где есть `header`, с боковая панель они остаются своего цвета и не меняются.
2. Как заменить эту иконку на белую после нажатия

вот разметка:

```css
body {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/external-bearicons-glyph-bearicons/344/external-moon-halloween-bearicons-glyph-bearicons.png" style="width: 10%; height: 10%;"></button>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Нужно больше кода, чтобы можно было посмотреть на работающем примере.
Предположу, что:
1. Для смены темы оформления вы добавляете/убираете класс. Видимо, для хедера и боковой панели указаны свои жесткие стили и общий класс для body не может их перебить.
2. Точно так же, как меняете класс у body, поменяйте класс и у кнопки, а в новом классе пропишите путь до новой иконки.

Comment: Всё же работает. Подвязывайтесь к классу `.dark-mode` и перебивайте стили на темные – будет дочернее темными. А так, магическим образом оно не появится.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить фильтр с инверсией:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/external-bearicons-glyph-bearicons/344/external-moon-halloween-bearicons-glyph-bearicons.png" style="width: 10%; height: 10%;"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете рассмотреть вариант переключения с тёмной темы на светлую с помощью кнопки:

```js
let button = document.getElementById('toggleButton');
let logo = document.getElementById('logo');

let darkImageURL = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuKoK.png";
let lightImageURL = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJSxu.png";

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if(this.innerHTML === "Ночь") {
    document.body.style.background = "black";
    this.innerHTML = "День";
    logo.src = darkImageURL;
  }
  else {
    document.body.style.background = "white";
    this.innerHTML = "Ночь";
    logo.src = lightImageURL;
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="toggleButton">Ночь</button>

  <img id="logo" class="nav_logo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJSxu.png" alt="original logo" width="100" height="100"/>
</body>
```

[Источник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1384919/28748)